# contiguous conditional format

Tags: conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I need to conditional format a group of cells that are contiguous,by filling the color. These are initials, however if the initials appear again, and are not contiguous they must be treated as new or different.

Mc Mc Mc Gk Nc Wg Wg Mc

in the example  only the first 3 "Mc" would be conditional formatted, the last Mc would be ignored.
"Wg" (which appears twice) would also be contiguous conditional formatted.
Should another set of "Mc" or any other set of initials) appear latter in the
row, conditional format would again apply.

If only a single set of initials appears, > no conditional format.
it would also be helpful if each set of contiguous conditional formatted cell could alternate color.
I can get the first group to C.F., but any reoccurrence of the same initials is treated as part of the first Contiguous group.

thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question to be more easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in B1:I1 and A1 does not contain the same as B1, select that range and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(A1=B1,B1=C1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your Fill of choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.